# Problems with pip or pip3 install requirements.txt what I should to do to fix this error?

Tags: python, linux, pip, setup.py, kali-linux

I run into the error below when running either command lines;

```py
# Using pip
pip install requirements.txt
# Using pip3
pip3 install requirements.txt
```

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>            command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/pip-egg-info
>                cwd: /tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/
>           Complete output (10 lines):
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "", line 1, in 
>             File "/tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/setup.py", line 2, in 
>               import poster
>             File "/tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/poster/**init**.py", line 29, in 
>               import poster.streaminghttp
>             File "/tmp/pip-install-evkbiocv/poster/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 61
>               print "send:", repr(value)
>                           ^
>           SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>           ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have to do: `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and needs to be `print("send: %s" % repr(value))`

Comment: Looks like you're using python3 and the file is written in python2

Comment: But Im try to pip install -r requirements.txt and then I have this error

Comment: Try this **Python -m pip install -r requirements.txt**

Comment: from directory python????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ‘“ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:” when trying to install watchdog using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423367/how-to-fix-error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-when-trying-to-inst)

Answer (score 2):

[`poster`](https://pypi.org/project/poster/) — the latest version was released in 2011. Obviously the package is for Python 2 and abandoned.

For HTTP use [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: so what I need to do?

Comment: sorry for this question, but I never dealt with requests

Comment: If you gonna use `poster` — switch to Python 2.7. As for `requests` — the package has extra good docs.

Comment: @AndreySima, you're using a Python 2 library on Python 3. Your choices are: Use a Python3 compatible library or use Python 2. I'd recommend using another library, as the responder recommended.