# How to fix the Error: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip

I was going to install epanettools using pip.

```
pip install epanettools
```

But I ran into an error shown below:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ziyuan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ziyuan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4nq1zwm9\\epanettools_e084a922f7b240baa95c32e399a3fca7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ziyuan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4nq1zwm9\\epanettools_e084a922f7b240baa95c32e399a3fca7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ziyuan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w1loj73h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ziyuan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\epanettools' Check the logs for full command output.
```

In my computer, I have installed the VS code.
Appreicate a lot if any advice to fix this error!

Comment: You may get some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423646/14429185) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the the beginning, I just tried to install epanettools with python 3.8.5. Then I installed it with lower version (3.7) of python, it works.